# How do I reset a td to it's native width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is a small demonstration of what my problem is:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2Pqw/4/

After sizing the red `td` to a certain width, I would like to set it back to what it was before. Applying 25% will not make it adjust dynamically like the other `td`s, it's just stuck at 25% which you can see when the black box changes it's size.

So I guess my questions are:

1. What is a `td`'s width before it is set manually?
2. How do I reset it?

Any ideas? Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting it to width: auto?

Comment: td's will auto size when no specific width is set. So if you have four td's each will have 25% width of table width when all divs have same inner html.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, he tries to animate it.

Comment: Maybe this colud help you: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

Comment: Please don’t answer to a question with another question. If you are unsure it works, test it. If you don’t want to, suggest it as a comment to the question, so either you or someone else can add it as an answer after testing.

Comment: Someone stood up with a wrong foot today. The guy solved his problem, right?

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow FAQ. Stackoverflow is not only for solving individuals problems and then not caring anymore. It is more, and meant to help further people.

Comment: @Kissaki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question This looks like an innocent enough example.

Comment: I don’t think we should introduce rhetorical questions as answers here … They may be valid in conversations, but not in long-standing facts, wikis, and other factual documentation like here. You don’t prefer this answer over Samuels, do you?

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I think we can finish this because it is getting totally unrelated @Kissaki

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If just reset all tds to default width at once, just use `width: auto`. However, if you want to animate it there, it is little more complicated. You need to save the width of each of the columns to variable and then animate it back.

Here is updated example from jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Pqw/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var blaW = $('#bla').width(), beW = $('#be').width();

$("#bla").animate({ width: "500px" }, 1000, function () {})
         .animate({width: blaW+'px'}, 1000, function () {});
$("#be").delay(2500)
        .animate({ width: "500px" }, 1000, function () {})
        .animate({width: beW+'px' }, 1000, function () {});
});
```

And html:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td style="background-color:Aqua;">salamander</td>
  <td style="background-color:Red;" id="bla">s</td>
  <td style="background-color:Black;" id="be">s</td>
  <td style="background-color:Green;">s</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was set to `auto`. you can see it in Chrome's Developer Tools or Firebug under "Default Styles"

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to add and remove a class setting a certain width. If class is removed, it would fall back to the % width.

Comment: It looks like he wants animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set any style (not just `width`) using JavaScript (or jQuery, since it's just fancy JS), then you can reset it by setting the style to `""` (empty string). This will basically remove that style property from the element's inline style, letting the stylesheet take over again.